# Find files excluding some directories

Tags: command-line, find

I am working with the following directory structure:

```
onathan@Aristotle:~/EclipseWorkspaces/ShellUtilities/ShellUtilities$ ls -R
.:
calculateTargetDay  CustomizeIso  ec  makeExecutable  Models  modifyElementList  Sourced  test file  Testing  valrelease

./Models:
testcase

./Sourced:
colors  stddefs  stdFunctions  SupportTesting

./Testing:
test  testCalculateTargetDay  testColors  testModifyElementList  testStddefs  testStdFunctions  testSupportTesting  tst
```

What I want to do is to run a command on all files in the top level directory and in the directory **Testing**. I do not want to run the command on the files in the directories **Sourced** and **Models**. To do this I ran the following command:

```
find . -name Sourced -prune -name Models -prune ! -name '\.*'  -execdir echo '{}' \;
```

This example did not run the command against any of the files in the directory structure.

When I ran the following command against the same directory structure:

```
find . ! -name '\.*'  -execdir echo '{}' \;
```

I got the following result

```
./calculateTargetDay
./CustomizeIso
./Testing
./testModifyElementList
./test
./testColors
./testStdFunctions
./testCalculateTargetDay
./testStddefs
./testSupportTesting
./tst
./test file
./modifyElementList
./ec
./Sourced
./stdFunctions
./stddefs
./SupportTesting
./colors
./valrelease
./Models
./testcase
./makeExecutable
```

As you can see I can run one command against the directory tree and have it apply to all files or I can try to be selective and wind up running against no files. How can I get the selective application of a command that I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Regex, from the parent directory:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./([^/]+|Testing/.*)$'
```

`\./([^/]+|Testing/.*)$` will find all files (`-type f`) in the current directory and in the `Testing` directory only.

To run a command, add `-exec` action:

```
find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./([^/]+|Testing/.*)$' -exec echo {} \;
```

Replace `echo` with your actual command.

**Example:**

```
$ find . -type f                                                                           
./foo
./Sourced/src
./Testing/test
./bar
./spam
./Models/model

$ find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./([^/]+|Testing/.*)$'                 
./foo
./Testing/test
./bar
./spam

$ find . -type f -regextype posix-egrep -regex '\./([^/]+|Testing/.*)$' -exec echo {} \;
./foo
./Testing/test
./bar
./spam
```

Comment: Much cleaner than a traditional find solution thanks.

Comment: @Jonathan Exactly. When i see many `-prune`, -`o` etc, i just move to Regex to keep it cleaner.